# UITableView didSelectRow not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In an iOS app I have a ViewController that has a ContainerView in which a ViewController (say VC2) resides, using an Embed Segue. This VC2 owns a UITableView and it's datasource and delegate are set to the VC2 and also conforms to the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols.
Now the cells are rendered perfectly, so the dataSource seems good. But when I try to select a row, nothing happens, so there seems to be a problem with the delegate.
However, the delegate methods **willDisplayCell** and **shouldHightlightRowAt** do get called. And I only implemented these method to check whether the delegate is set up correctly. And no, I did **NOT** implement the didDeselectRowAt method, which is a common mistake.

In IB the tableview owns two dynamic prototype cells, the **Selection** property is set to **Single Selection** and the **Style** is set to **Plain**. Both the UITableViewCells have a **Style** set to **Custom** and **Selection** is set to **Default**.

Why doesn't the didSelectRowAt method get called? I did check the isEditing property, which is set to false; editing is not relevant in my case.

this is my didSelect method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    print("didSelectRowAt (indexPath.row)") 
}
```

I use Swift 4.

Comment: can you include the didSelect method declaration with the swift version you use

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Add your code to your question, it will help us to find the issue.

Comment: Do you have other gesture recognizer on the controller?

Comment: Yes, a swipe gesture which is set to the main view of the ViewController.
This is used to animate the container to the left out of the screen; the container is used as a menu.

Comment: Ok, you can try the Quentin answer or you can try to disable the gesture and open the menu only from a button on the navigation bar.

Comment: Did you put `your_tableView.delegate  = self`?

Comment: Do you have any button/gesture added to VC2?

Comment: Why dont you show us more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but it seems that Xcode has given me a really hard time.
I just deleted the ViewController from the storyboard and built it up from scratch again. Also created a new file for the VC and now everything works just as expected. Sometimes the is the way to go is delete all your work and start over again and in this particular case... it was.

I really cannot say what could be the cause; but it seems that something got messed up in the storyboard file. At least, that is my best guess.

Wasted some time... Thanks anyway for attending...